# How to derive with respect to a Matrix element with Sympy

Tags: python, matrix, sympy, derivative

Given the product of a matrix and a vector

A.v

with A of shape (m,n) and v of dim n, where m and n are symbols, I need to calculate the Derivative with respect to the matrix elements.
I haven't found the way to use a proper vector, so I started with 2 `MatrixSymbol`:

```
n, m = symbols('n m')
j = tensor.Idx('j')
i = tensor.Idx('i')
l = tensor.Idx('l')
h = tensor.Idx('h')
A = MatrixSymbol('A', n,m)
B = MatrixSymbol('B', m,1)
C=A*B
```

Now, if I try to derive with respect to one of A's elements with the indices I get back the unevaluated expression:

```
diff(C, A[i,j])
>>>> Derivative(A*B, A[i, j])
```

If I introduce the indices in C also (it won't let me use only one index in the resulting vector) I get back the product expressed as a Sum:

```
C[l,h]
>>>> Sum(A[l, _k]*B[_k, h], (_k, 0, m - 1))
```

If I derive this with respect to the matrix element I end up getting 0 instead of an expression with the `KroneckerDelta`, which is the result that I would like to get:

```
diff(C[l,h], A[i,j])
>>>> 0
```

I wonder if maybe I shouldn't be using MatrixSymbols to start with.  How should I go about implementing the behaviour that I want to get?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The git version of SymPy (and the next version) handles this better:

```
In [55]: print(diff(C[l,h], A[i,j]))
Sum(KroneckerDelta(_k, j)*KroneckerDelta(i, l)*B[_k, h], (_k, 0, m - 1))
```

Answer (score 7):

SymPy [does not yet know matrix calculus](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/5858); in particular, one cannot differentiate `MatrixSymbol` objects. You can do this sort of computation with `Matrix` objects filled with arrays of symbols; the drawback is that the matrix sizes must be explicit for this to work.

Example:

```
from sympy import *
A = Matrix(symarray('A', (4, 5)))
B = Matrix(symarray('B', (5, 3)))
C = A*B
print(C.diff(A[1, 2]))
```

outputs:

```
Matrix([[0, 0, 0], [B_2_0, B_2_1, B_2_2], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]])
```