# Derivatives of a matrix using Sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I am learning Sympy to know the Symbolic operations in Python. I want to find out the derivative of a matrix.

[image: example matrix]

How could I derivate the matrix in respect to b.

```
import sympy as sp
B = sp.Matrix([[(a*c),(b**2)],[(b*d),(d*a)]])
B
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41581002/how-to-derive-with-respect-to-a-matrix-element-with-sympy) can not help me to give my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the usual [matrix-by-scalar derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Matrix-by-scalar) and that you're using sympy 1.7, then the following should work:

```
import sympy as sp
a, b, c, d = sp.symbols("a b c d")
B = sp.Matrix([[(a*c),(b**2)],[(b*d),(d*a)]])
B.diff(b)
```

Returns:

```
Matrix([
[0, 2*b],
[d,   0]])
```

Which seems right to me. More [here](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/matrices.html#matrixcalculus-class-reference).